# What is the ship icon near Ysgramor's Tomb?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On my way to Ysgramor's Tomb, I saw a ship outline to the northwest and went to investigate.  I went out into the ice flows and the ship outline on the compass began to highlight as I got closer.  Then, it went poof and disappeared.  I never was notified that I arrived some place, and it does not show up on my map.  Does anyone know what this ship is and how do I reach it?

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about.  I tried swimming down to it, but died a few times trying to investigate... by drowning

Comment: On PC (I don't know other consoles, must be tested) there's a bug that if you down to water your head (on first person camera) to the half, and you can see the water line at half of screen, you are able to view all objects under water without the "fog" of a disturb water.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an under water ship, which can be investigated, if you want to investigate fully i recommend either a water breathing potion or spell.

Comment: so it won't trigger that I've been there unless I swim down to it?  is it worth investigating?

Comment: Yes you have to go to it to get the icon to become white (dunno how else to put it), as for 'is it worth it?' i'm not sure as i cannot remember what is there nor do i remember the name to look it up in the wiki. Go there then look the name in the wiki to find this out...

Comment: @IrishJMA Is it worth investigating? Depends on how much you like [iceberg lettuce](http://i.imgur.com/ZFSLm.jpg).

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like [Pilgrim's Trench](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pilgrim%27s_Trench)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any loot down there and other than for the purposes of adding a discovered location to your map, no, there isn't much point in going down there. If you do though, have a few water breathing potions well stocked and some health potions if you begin to drown.

Comment: If you want an answer, please [ask your own question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Adding a post is reserved for actual answers only.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been to the ship yet since I only heard about where it was now but I do plan on searching it. You could try a water breathing enchantment or something. I'm not sure where but I found a helmet once with the enchantment and I just put it into a ring. Should help if you don't want any healing potions or water breathing ones.